# How to exclude __init__ of parent class but include __init__ of parent of parent class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Is there any way possible that the `Third` class can inherit the `First` class, as well as methods of `Second` class except the `__init__` method of Second class?

```
class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("first")

    def f1(self):
        print("f1")


class Second(First):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("second")

    def f2(self):
        print("f2")


class Third(Second):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("third")
        self.f1()
        self.f2()
        self.f3()

    def f3(self):
        print("f3")


Third()
```

Current output

```
first
second
third
f1
f2
f3
```

Expecting output

```
first
third
f1
f2
f3
```

Comment: Well, in principle, yes. Just don't call `super().__init__()` in the `Third` class. Or call `First.__init__(self)`? <= not tried that  myself.

Comment: I would question why you want this design in the first place.  This may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Classes can inherit from multiple parents, not only via nesting - see the `MultiDevrived` example here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/multiple-inheritance and use `Third(First, Second)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Third` is already overriding the `__init__` method, so all you have to do is use the explicit class name whose `__init__` you want to use instead of calling `super`.

```
# Inside Third.__init__
First.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes can inherit from multiple parents, not only via nesting - see the `MultiDevrived` example here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/multiple-inheritance.

You would declare with `Third(First, Second)` so that methods from `First` are used before those of `Second` in case of naming collisions.

Comment: This gives "TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases First, Second". I don't know why it gave this particular error, but it's basically not useful to use multiple inheritance where one class is a subclass of another. MRO is complicated. If I use `Third(Second, First)`, the error goes away, but it's obviously useless.

Comment: `MRO is complicated`! I guess the presence of `Second(First)` is what breaks stuff in this case.